# H2 DB driver not in classpath

Tags: java, h2

I'm trying to connect to my embedded H2 database via Java. I found various threads and tutorials on this and now have this code:

```
Connection con = null;
Properties connectionProps = new Properties();
connectionProps.put("user", "username");
connectionProps.put("password", "password");
try {
    Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:~/test", connectionProps);
```

I got the "no suitable driver found for jdbc:h2:~/test" error message. I found the Class.forName(...) in some threads as a solution to this, but it doesn't seem to be working (ClassNotFoundException).

I read that the driver is probably not in my classpath, but don't really know what I need to do with that information. In the database view of IntelliJ the driver seems to work just fine (I can click reload drivers and it confirms the h2 driver). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using a build system like Gradle?  If not, have you acquired the jar?  You're right that unless you downloaded it, it won't be in your classpath as it isn't in the standard library.

Intellij has good db integration, so it is able to download the jar for the classpath that it sets up exclusively for itself.  But the moment you try to access it outside of one of Intellij's  specific integrations, it won't be there unless you also include it

Comment: Is that the jarin the H2\bin folder? How do I have to include it?

Comment: Very likely yes.  How are you running this program?  Command line?  Intellij run configuration?  Also, can you tell me if you're using gradle?  If you are, there is a much easier way that doesn't require you to ever touch the jar file yourself

Comment: Intellij run configuration and not using gradle

Comment: Your Class.forName line did it for me :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to add to the classpath.  I recommend trying to understand this page https://howtodoinjava.com/java/basics/java-classpath/ for more information on different strategies that have similar, but different results.

Probably the simplest way for just this project, would be to edit the "run configuration" that you are using, and add a new VM option:

```
–classpath /path/to/local/h2/driver.jar
```

Use an absolute path to the jar, and this will allow it to be present in the classpath when running it this way.  In the link I shared, this is the same as adding the command line argument to the `java` or `javac` command, so this argument will work outside of intellij on the command line as well.

**Edit:**

Based on the comments, it seems like you might be using the %PROGRAMFILES% environment variable, with a fully qualified path.

Try this instead:

```
-classpath %PROGRAMFILES%\H2\bin\h2-1.4.200.jar
```

If you were to run the following command in your command prompt

```
echo %PROGRAMFILES%
```

I suspect you'd get the response:

```
C:\Program Files
```

Which is not the x86 version.  So. Either use the environment variable and omit the part of the path it's value represents (eliminating the `C:\` part)

or, if that's not the correct Program Files folder at all, then avoid it and try (note the quotes which are required because a folder has spaces in it's name):

```
--classpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\H2\bin\h2-1.4.200.jar"
```

Comment: could I also just drag the jar into the src folder and set the path there? Also, if I added this (`-classpath C:/%ProgramFiles(x86)%/H2/bin/h2-1.4.200.jar`) in the VM options, I just get a "Could not find or load class com.company.Main" error message.

Comment: You can.  Instead of the src folder, which should be only where files to be compiled and their resources will go.  This is a dependency which by convention should go elsewhere.  Instead, I recommend creating a `lib` folder adjacent to `src` to house all your third party libraries like the h2 driver, then point your path there.  If it still doesn't work, try without using environment variables to fill in the path, just to rule that out as your problem.

Comment: Tried with `-classpath C:\%ProgramFiles(x86)%\H2\bin\h2-1.4.200.jar"` now. I'm a bit confused now, does this need to go in VM options (which still gets me the class com.company.Main not found error) or in environment variables (which gives no error for that but still the ClassNotFoundException for org.h2.Driver)?

Comment: Oh, I might've noticed something, sorry, I'm not familiar with Windows much.  The path you're choosing, are you intentionally using an environment variable for ProgramFiles?  It looks as though you're attempting a hybrid of two pathing solutions.  I'm going to update my answer with some path snippets instead of burying them here. One minute.

Comment: **Latest Try:*** I now used `-classpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\H2\bin\h2-1.4.200.jar"`, which didn't give me an error for the Main class, but still the exact same errors for the org.h2.Driver (ClassNotFoundException) and jdbc:h2:~/test (SQLException no suitable driver found)

Comment: Also, as a note (not sure if it matters): Using the database navigator plugin, I can connect to the database via Intellij UI and run SQL queries. Just in the code it's not working.